# How can I relax the equality constraint in this problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, relaxation

Consider the following problem
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{x,y}
    \quad & f(x,y), \\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & \exp(x) + \exp(y) = 1
    \end{aligned} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $f : (-\infty,0) \times (-\infty,0) \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ is convex and monotone increasing in $x$ and $y$ (in the sense that, if $x_1 \leq x_2$ and $y_1 \leq y_2$, then $f(x_1,y_1) \leq f(x_2,y_2)$). Also, note that the left-hand side of the constraint is non-linear, convex, and strictly monotone increasing in $x$ and $y$ (in the sense that, if $x_1 < x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$, then $\exp(x_1) + \exp(y_1) < \exp(x_2) + \exp(y_2)$).

The problem in $(1)$ is *almost* convex. The challenge here is that the constraint defines a non-linear curve in $\mathbb R^2$. My initial attempt at making this problem convex was to relax this constraint into $\exp(x) + \exp(y) \leq 1$ and then show that this relaxation is tight (that is, solving $(1)$ with the constraint $\exp(x) + \exp(y) \leq 1$ yields the same solution as solving $(1)$ with the constraint $\exp(x) + \exp(y) = 1$).

However, this approach does not work here, since, in order to decrease $f$, we would need to decrease $x$ and $y$ (because $f$ is monotone increasing in $x$ and $y$), but this would in-turn decrease $\exp(x) + \exp(y)$ since it is strictly monotone increasing. This means that, starting at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ that is inside the convex feasible set defined by the constraint $\exp(x) + \exp(y) \leq 1$, $\exp(x) + \exp(y) = 1$ would not be satisfied no matter how much $x$ and $y$ are decreased in order to decrease $f$.

Ideally, there should be some invertible function $g : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ that I can apply to both sides of the equality constraint such that the constraint becomes $g(\exp(x) + \exp(y)) = g(1)$ and so that $g(\exp(x) + \exp(y))$ is convex and strictly monotone decreasing in $(x,y)$ on the left-hand side and $g(1) = 1$ on the right-hand side. This would mean that the new constraint is $g(\exp(x) + \exp(y)) = 1$ and so I can apply the relaxation as before to get $g(\exp(x) + \exp(y)) \leq 1$. In this case, the relaxation should be tight, since the left-hand side of the inequality increases as $(x,y)$ is decreased, which also decreases the objective $f$. However, I'm not sure of the following:

1. Which function $g$ to choose that fits this case (I've thought about $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, but this didn't work).
2. Whether there is a better approach than mine to relax the constraint in $(1)$ so that $(1)$ becomes a convex optimization problem.

Comment: Just use a local or global non-convex solver, unless you don't care about how good the solution is, in which case you can do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x, \log(1 - \exp(x))).$ Try plotting that to see if it is unimodal and, if so, whether the min is attained in the interior or only approached (infimum) as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ or as $x\rightarrow 0$. If it is unimodal with an interior minimum, you have a one-dimensional problem, which can be solved by bisection search or golden section search, or maybe by gradient descent if $f$ is smooth.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I rewrite the equality constraint $\exp(x) + \exp(y) = 1$ as $y = \log(1-\exp(x))$ and then substitute this value of $y$ into my objective function $f(x,y) = f(x,\log(1-\exp(x)))$ to get an unconstrained 1D optimization problem. Is this right?

Comment: It's not exactly unconstrained -- you still have the domain restriction $-\infty < x < 0$ --  but yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Comment: You are correct. I plotted $f(x,\log(1-\exp(x)))$ and it is indeed unimodal. Thank you for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @prubin's answer, another approach, which may be useful when $x$ and $y$ are high-dimensional, is to solve the problem in $(1)$ as a *difference-of-convex* (DC) program. This approach is described in the paper

> Lipp, T., Boyd, S. Variations and extension of the convex–concave procedure. Optim Eng 17, 263–287 (2016).

The main idea is to re-write the equality constraint $\exp(x) + \exp(y) = 1$ as the following two inequality constraints:
\begin{align}
\left[\exp\left(x\right) + \exp\left(y\right)\right] - 1 &\leq 0 \\
1 - \left[\exp\left(x\right) + \exp\left(y\right)\right] &\leq 0
\end{align}
The left-hand side of both inequality constraints is a difference of convex functions. In addition, since the objective function is convex, then $(1)$ qualifies as a DC program. There is also a [Python package](https://github.com/cvxgrp/dccp) that can be used to solve DC programs.